# Unity Custom window with side by side tabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a custom window editor in unity, and I can't get multiple tabs to load side by side when I click on the menu item.

This is what I have gotten so far:

[image: Dock 1]

This is how I would like it to look when it loads:

[image: Dock 2]

Here is what I am doing to get the effect of the first image. What do I need to add/change to get the effect of the second image?

```
[MenuItem ("GameObject/My Editor")]
public static void ShowWindow() {
    EditorWindow hierarchyWindow = GetWindow<QEHierarchy>("Hierarchy");
    EditorWindow eventsWindow = GetWindow<QEEvents>("Events", typeof(QEHierarchy));

    hierarchyWindow.Show();
}
```

Comment: bit of a shot in the dark but there is: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal.html not sure if it works in this context though

Comment: No, that is for displaying items in the same window side by side, not two windows side by side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding from [Unity Scripting Reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.GetWindow.html) the second parameter in `GetWindow` method defines the other tab after which you want to dock your new tab. Therefore, considering your code the second parameter `typeof(QEHierarchy)` is the culprit that is placing your new tab side by side inside the same window.

Well try removing it.

Further Explanation (From the link I have added above)

```
public static T GetWindow(string title, params Type[] desiredDockNextTo);
```

Where:

- **T** -> The type of the window. Must derive from EditorWindow.
- **title** -> If GetWindow creates a new window, it will get this title. If this value is null, use the class name as title.
- **desiredDockNextTo** -> An array of EditorWindow types that the window will attempt to dock onto.